# Code not working in IE to hide and unhide Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm no good a JS asn the code I'm using is what a colleague put together for me and it works fine in Chrome but isn't playing nice in IE.

The code is to allow me to have a list that I can click to show a hidden div and when I click another link in the list it hide the last div and unhides the last clicked etc.

Here is my JS

```
function hideClass(id){
    $('.objections').addClass('hide');
    $('#'+id+'_container').removeClass('hide');

}
```

and I have this in my HTML

```
 onclick="hideClass(this.id)"
```

Is there anyway to alter this for it to work in IE?

As I said, I'm not good at JS only HTML CSS so I have no idea where to start

Comment: I think you should tag jQuery in this question since you are using jQuery.

Comment: What version of jQuery and what version of IE are you using?

Comment: need to see the html produced in IE

Comment: @jfriend00 jquery-1.9.1 and I believe it's either IE 10 or 11. Unsure as it's another colleague using IE (some people just won't jump ship)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to know exactly what's failing.  I guessed at what you were probably doing and came up with this basic code, which worked in IE for me.  However, IE did initially block scripts and I had to click to allow.  So watch for that.

```js
function hideClass(id) {
  $('.objections').addClass('hide');
  $('#' + id + '_container').removeClass('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myID" class="objections" onclick="hideClass(this.id)">
    <h1>I OBJECT!</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="myID_container" class="hide">
    <h1>Can you see me now?</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Since you are using jQuery though, this code is a bit cleaner:

```js
function hideClass(div) {
  $(div).hide();
  $('#' + div.id + '_container').show();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myID" class="objections" onclick="hideClass(this)">
    <h1>I OBJECT!</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="myID_container" style="display:none">
    <h1>Can you see me now?</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```